# How do I install a glass tile backsplash on 1/2" drywall?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, tile

I am currently building a house and am at the point where the builder has just finished the drywall and is ready for the kitchen cabinets and countertops to be installed.  There will be no backsplash but I did intend to put a glass mosaic tile between the counter tops and upper cabinets for use as a backsplash.

It slipped my mind at the time to ask for the builder to use cement board behind the cabinets where this tile will eventually go, and it is a little late for me to change my mind now that the drywall has been finished.

My question is, what is the most appropriate way to install a glass tile backsplash in a kitchen that is completely 1/2" drywall?  Is it not appropriate to place this tile over regular drywall?  If appropriate, should paint be removed first before placing thinset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it onto the drywall. You want it smooth and to not have a glaze, so you may have to sand it. If its been painted with a topcoat, you may want to paint it again with a primer.

Use mortor that is specifically designed for glass tiles, not ceramic tiles.